# Build Yocto image on a RPi B+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, yocto, meta-raspberrypi

I am new to Yocto, but I was wondering if it is feasible to build a Yocto rpi-basic-image on Raspbian using a B+ model with a 128GB SD card.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow since it is not about programming. General computer related questions should be on [the SuperUser site](https://superuser.com/) and questions about raspberry pi should be on [the Rapberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I guess you are wrong since there are 1206 other questions with the tag of Yocto project, but unfortunately none of them could answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

*On* a RPi?  Theoretically yes, but don't as you'll be there for days.